# Calling .net assembly from vb6 results in runtime error 424

Tags: .net, vb6, regasm

I'm running into some trouble calling a .net assembly from vb6 and was hoping SO could help.

In VB.net I built a ComClass and kept the default constructor and GUIDs.
 When deploying, I REGASM.exe the dll, which is located in the same folder as the VB6 exe. The .net dll references two other .net dll's, both of which are in the same folder.

I am trying to load the .net assembly using the VB6 function CreateObject(). When running the VB6 exe, I get the following error

```
 Run-time rror '424':
    Object required
```

This is occuring on a Windows 2000 server. I am able to create the object on an XP box, however i'm not sure exactly how different the states of the two boxes are.

If anyone has any thoughts, it would be much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try REGASM /CODEBASE. This allows you to load the dll where it is instead of the GAC.